# ¿Ir al gimnasio a ejercitarse físicamente se puede considerar un deporte?

Tags: significado, acepciones

Recientemente me han surgido algunas dudas acerca de las diferencias entre "deporte" y "ejercicio físico".
Según el diccionario de la RAE un deporte (primera acepción) es una

> Actividad física, ejercida como juego o competición, cuya práctica supone entrenamiento y sujeción a normas

por lo que ir al gimnasio a ejercitarse físicamente no se podría considerar como deporte.
No obstante, en la segunda acepción se define como

> Recreación, pasatiempo, placer, diversión o ejercicio físico, por lo común al aire libre

Con respecto a esta acepción, si que debería considerarse como tal.
La primera acepción es bastante restrictiva y la segunda muy abierta, por lo tanto ¿deberíamos utilizar siempre la segunda a la hora de considerar una actividad un deporte?

Answer (score 3):

Me parece que la diferencia entre la primera y la segunda acepción de "deporte" es que la primera se usa con un sentido concreto y contable, mientras que la segunda se utiliza con un sentido abstracto e incontable:

1. hacer/practicar **un** deporte (un deporte en particular)
2. hacer deporte (deportes en general, o ejercicio físico en un sentido más amplio)

De todos modos, "hacer ejercicio físico" me parece más abarcativo y genérico que "hacer deporte". También es muy común hablar de "hacer actividad física".